# Using QtCharts in Qt Creator with python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-creator, qt-quick, qtcharts

I am using Qt Creator to create a QtQuick program using Python. I want to add the QtCharts module to my QML files, but I get the error message

> QML module not found (QtCharts)

In a QtQuick project using C++, one would include QtCharts by adding `QT += charts` in the .pro file. 
Is there a similar command to add in the main.pyproj file? 
Note that the program runs correctly when built through the python script, but I want to access the features used by the designer in Qt Creator.

The main.pyproject is as follows:

```
{"files": ["main.py","frontend/main.qml"]}
```

The main.py file:

```
import os
import sys

import PyQt5.QtQml
import PyQt5.QtCore
import PyQt5.QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE'] = 'Default'
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = PyQt5.QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()


    engine.load('frontend/main.qml')
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the frontend/main.qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtCharts 2.10

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    title: 'Neuron Network Sandbox'

    ChartView {
        width: 400
        height: 300
        antialiasing: true

        PieSeries {
            id: pieSeries
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PyQt5 or PySide2? provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc added. I used PyQt5, but it works fine when using python to run. I can't get QtCharts to load when using Qt Creator

Comment: mmm, does that code work for you from the console or CMD? If so, are you sure you're using the same python?

Comment: mmm, it seems strange to me. Can you create, edit and compile a project similar to the one you provide but written in C++? Qt Creator can directly open .qml, have you tried opening main.qml directly in Qt Creator?

Comment: @eyllanesc I will try building it in C++. Yes I am editing the .qml file in Qt Creator.

Comment: @eyllanesc I was able to build and run qt example files chartthemes and qml surface with uses charts and data visualization respectively, but it still says that I do not have neither installed when I enter designer in Qt Creator.